# Can Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server scale horizontally?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, scalability, horizontal-scaling

I need to handle authentication of hundreds of thousands of users.

For the moment I have bunch of microservices and a single SpringBoot app configured as Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server.

Does Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server support horizontal scaling?

(for example, Dockerize that Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server and use AWS ECS to launch multiple instances)

I cound't find any official Spring Security OAuth2 documentation talking about scalability.

Comment: isn't the scaling all about when CPU or memory related thresholds have reached, and if you have a docker image for application that takes care of Oauth authorization then probably with beanstalk like services you can configure the scaling too, isn't it so

Comment: Yes, but there are further things that concern me. Just to make up an example, maybe the authorization server is tracking the login session, then what happens if my next call hits a different server instance? Does it support shared memory or some sort of replication?

Comment: here I shall put a correction, when we talk about scalability, we say that either use tokens or otherwise if you are using sticky sessions then probably new users have to go to new instances only and then you have like how will you manage the auto scalability i.e. mark the sessions as null or void after the newly created instances die upon scaling down again

Comment: for other cases like SSO login using google OAuth, there are docker images for that

Comment: Say I have a webapp sticked to a specific server instance. When the webapp calls to a springboot microservice, that microservice needs to validate the token by making a call to the authorization server. I think sticky session does not work in this case.

Comment: I couldn't find it but If there is a documentation that says that the Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server is stateless, then that will be super awesome.

Comment: I have to see the docs as well, will keep you posted